# Create notches/carvings on Cylinder Geometry

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, pixi.js

I am trying to recreate a scene but one specific detail is very challenging.

In this scene, the cylinder geometry surface has many small circular notches. Inside the notches, there are white lines. What I found particularly difficult is how to create all those notches on this surface? There are about 61 circular notches.

[image]

I have thought about using Clipping but it won’t necessarily work for the circular shape? Also, there are so many notches…

Does anyone know anything related to this in the documentation that I can take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this in a modeller like Blender.. using a boolean subtract modifier, then export to something like GLTF, and import into three.

Even if you managed to do it in pure three.js, it will be hard to get the smoothing right, since you'll need crisp edges to make the embossed circles to show up...

Comment: Thank you. I have never heard of Blender but just checked its' documentation. It does seem like the right solution.
Will give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, using a 3d modeling program to actually create the geometry is one solution. Another option is to use a normal map or parallax mapping to give the illusion of depth for all those circles.

[Here](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_displacementmap.html) is a THREE.js example with normal maps.

Hope that helps!